# Why alarm doesn't work if I close the application

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager, android-pendingintent, alarm

I have an application, what I have written in Kotlin in Android studio. The problem is that when the alarm clock should start working, but it doesn bot when the application on the phone is closed, then nothing works and does not start. May be I have very simple problem. Maybe you can help me. Thanks!

I try everything I can. This is code:

```
package com.example.gpsallarm

import android.app.AlarmManager
import android.app.PendingIntent
import android.content.Context
import android.content.Intent
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.location.LocationManager
import android.os.Build
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.TextView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContract
import androidx.activity.result.contract.ActivityResultContracts
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import com.example.gpsallarm.databinding.ActivityMainBinding
import com.google.android.gms.location.FusedLocationProviderClient
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices
import com.google.android.material.timepicker.MaterialTimePicker
import com.google.android.material.timepicker.MaterialTimePicker.INPUT_MODE_CLOCK
import com.google.android.material.timepicker.TimeFormat
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.*
import kotlin.Pair
import kotlin.properties.Delegates
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.EventBus
import org.greenrobot.eventbus.Subscribe
import java.lang.Thread

class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    private lateinit var fusedLocationProviderClient: FusedLocationProviderClient
    private lateinit var coordinates_text : TextView
    private lateinit var coordinates_button : Button
    private var PERMISSION_ID = 1271
    var sdf : SimpleDateFormat = SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm", Locale.getDefault())
    var latitude : Double? = null
    var longitude : Double? = null
    private val backgroundLocation = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()){

    }
    private val locationPermission = registerForActivityResult(ActivityResultContracts.RequestMultiplePermissions()){
        when{
            it.getOrDefault(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, false)->{

                if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.Q){
                    if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION)!=PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                        backgroundLocation.launch(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_BACKGROUND_LOCATION))
                    }
                }

            }
            it.getOrDefault(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, false)->{

            }
        }
    }
    private var service:Intent?=null
    var picker:MaterialTimePicker?=null
    var isLocationGet = false

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        fusedLocationProviderClient = LocationServices.getFusedLocationProviderClient(this)
        coordinates_text = findViewById<TextView>(R.id.Location)
        coordinates_button = findViewById<Button>(R.id.GetPos)
        service = Intent(this, LocationService::class.java)
        coordinates_button.setOnClickListener{
            chek_permissions()
            setAlarm()
        }
    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()
        if(!EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)){
            EventBus.getDefault().register(this)
        }
    }

    private fun chek_permissions(){
        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT>=Build.VERSION_CODES.O){
            if(ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED || ActivityCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED){
                locationPermission.launch(arrayOf(android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION))
            }
            else{
                startService(service)
            }
        }
    }

    private fun setAlarm(){
        picker = MaterialTimePicker.Builder()
            .setTimeFormat(TimeFormat.CLOCK_24H)
            .setHour(12)
            .setMinute(0)
            .setTitleText("Select allarm time")
            .setInputMode(INPUT_MODE_CLOCK)
            .build()
        picker!!.addOnPositiveButtonClickListener{
            isLocationGet = true
        }
        picker!!.show(supportFragmentManager, "tag_picker")
    }

    fun setAlarmAfterTakeLocation(){
        if (isLocationGet) {
            val calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
            calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0)
            calendar.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0)
            calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, picker!!.minute)
            calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, picker!!.hour)
            val alarmManager = getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE) as AlarmManager
            val alarmClockInfo =
                AlarmManager.AlarmClockInfo(calendar.timeInMillis, getAlarmInfoPendingIntent())
            alarmManager.setAlarmClock(alarmClockInfo, getAlarmActivePendingIntent())
            Toast.makeText(
                this,
                "Будильник установлен на " + sdf.format(calendar.time),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
            stopService(service)
            isLocationGet = false
        }
    }
    private fun getAlarmInfoPendingIntent(): PendingIntent {
        val alarmInfoIntent = Intent(this, MainActivity::class.java)
        alarmInfoIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        alarmInfoIntent.putExtra("latitude", latitude)
        alarmInfoIntent.putExtra("longitude", longitude)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, alarmInfoIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
        } else {
            return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0, alarmInfoIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
    }
    private fun getAlarmActivePendingIntent(): PendingIntent {
        val intent = Intent(this, AlarmActivity::class.java)
        intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP and Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        intent.putExtra("latitude", latitude)
        intent.putExtra("longitude", longitude)
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.S) {
            return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_MUTABLE)
        } else {
            return PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 1, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT)
        }
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy()
        stopService(service)
        if(EventBus.getDefault().isRegistered(this)){
            EventBus.getDefault().unregister(this)
        }
    }

    @Subscribe
    fun receiveLocationEvent(locationEvent: LocationEvent){
        latitude = locationEvent.latitude!!
        longitude = locationEvent.longitude!!
        setAlarmAfterTakeLocation()
    }
}
```

Comment: You need have a background worker. What your app is doing is killing the process.. look into background workers and use it to keep the process running in the background